# Show expected and actual values for assertion failures

Tags: node.js, typescript, assert

When writing assertions for my tests, the assertion failures don't provide enough information without needing to open an IDE and start debugging.

For example, I have some code that uses the 'assert' library:

```
import * as assert from 'assert'

// some code

assert(someObject.getValue() === 0)
```

I just get

```
       AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: false == true
           + expected - actual

           -false
           +true
```

This error message isn't really meaningful. As a workaround, I added it in the message in the assertion:

```
assert(someObject.getValue() === 0, 
       '\nActual: ' + someObject.getValue() + 
       '\nExpected: ' + 0)
```

Is there a better, cleaner way to just show the expected & actual values without overriding the message on every assertion? I also tried to create an `assert` wrapper, but I wasn't able to extract the actual and expected values from the expression.

EDIT: `assert.strictEqual` resolves this issue for equalities only. But as soon as any other operator is included, then we have the same issue (e.g. `assert(someObject.getValue() > 0)`

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try instead `assert.strictEqual(someObject.getValue(), 0)`

Comment: strictEqual does work well for equality, actual and expected results aren't printed when using `>`, `<` expressions...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AssertionError` for this, passing it as the second argument when calling `assert`. For example, we want to check whether the synon data matches the real ones:

```
    const test = {
        trigger: (event, data) => { }
    };
    const spy = sinon.spy(test, 'trigger');

    test.trigger('event', 'data1'); // with invalid data to cause an error

    assert(spy.calledWithExactly('event', 'data2'), new AssertionError({
        message: 'trigger should be called with the proper arguments',
        actual: spy.getCalls()[0].args,
        expected: ['event', 'data2']
    }));
```

This will throw an error:

```
  AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: trigger should be called with the proper arguments
  + expected - actual

   [
     "event"
  -  "data1"
  +  "data2"
   ]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [assert.strictEqual(actual, expected[, message])](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_strictequal_actual_expected_message) to get actual/expected error messages without the need of the third message argument:

```
assert.strictEqual(someObject.getValue(), 0)
```

You'd get an error message such as:

```
// AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected inputs to be strictly equal:
//
// 1 !== 0
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: strictEqual does work well for equality, but actual and expected results aren't printed when using `>`, `<` expressions... how would I write `assert(someObject.getValue() > 0)`?

Comment: The example you provided you were comparing items using `===`, `strictEqual` would specifically solve that. If you need other types of conditions, you should update your questions. You may want to consider looking into testing frameworks such as Jest, Mocha, or similar that provide better reporting for tests/assertions like this. Thanks!